# why get requests are working, but post are not in the java servlets

Tags: java, servlets, post, http-post

I have a servlet, I call it from a get request, it works, good, but when i call it using this post request

```
private static void doPostToMultiPart() throws URISyntaxException,
            ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://localhost:8080/ServletExample1/multipart1");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println("response code = "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler()
                .handleResponse(response);
        System.out.println(responseString);
    }
```

I got an exception on the `handleResponse`, which is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractResponseHandler.handleResponse(AbstractResponseHandler.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:65)
    at com.clients.PostClient1.doPostToMultiPart(PostClient1.java:28)
    at com.clients.PostClient1.main(PostClient1.java:16)
```

and the status that I print is `404`

what wrong do I do pleaes?

#### Note

I could give you the servlet code, it is simple, but i though because i can make a get request, so the servlet is working fine and the problem is more likely from my post client request.

#### Update

when i do this

```
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related;");
```

it works, but when i do this:

```
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
```

i got the exception again. I want to return a custom message if the client requests a wrong content type. help please

Comment: What methods are defined in servlet? looks like `doPost` method is missing in servlet, can you verify?

Comment: @Marco, mate I had a very similar problem, its a very strange problem, different server require different way to send post request

Comment: @harsh doPost is there

Comment: @nafas why? aren't they use standard http protocol ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I really have no idea. never understood the problem, its most likely some sort of bug. did you try that method btw?

Comment: @harsh check my update please

Answer (score 0):

Post your servlet, and your web.xml if you're using one.  404 means that the requested resource was not found.  Are you missing doPost?

That means that `http://localhost:8080/ServletExample1/multipart1` is not a valid POST URL for some reason.  Put up the file(s) requested and let's see what they say.

Comment: I updated the question by web.xml that you required. However, your should have been a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

(take this as a long comment)

I know its strange but just try this Method to send Post (change as appropriate)

```
public static String sendPostV2(String data, String url) throws Exception {

    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod method = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod(url);
    if(data!=null){
       method.addParameter("data", data);
    }
    client.executeMethod(method);
    method.releaseConnection();
    try{
        return method.getResponseBodyAsString();
    }catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

I had a very similar problem, I have two different send Post method as one works for some server but not all and the other works otherway around, the first one is very similar to your code, and the second one (above code) is  just another approach to send Post.

Comment: Actually you are proposing a *reengineering*, while I was asking for a correction to my solution.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I did suggest that "take it as a long comment", obviously I'm quite aware this is not the answer to your solution. just wanted to see if it works for u